# Problems with memory management strategy

Tags: c++

in the newest The C++ Programming language book, Bjarne presents an alternative to an orthodox error handling, that is to use exceptions. This is in chapter 13.3.1, and he writes:

```
void test()
     // handle undiciplined resource acquisition
     // demonstrate that arbitrary actions are possible
{
     int* p = new int{7};                              // probably should use a unique_ptr (§5.2)
     int* buf = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));         // C-style allocation

     auto act1 = finally([&]{   delete p;
                                free(buf);             // C-style deallocation
                                cout<< "Goodby, Cruel world!\n";
                           }
                     );

     int var = 0;
     cout << "var = " << var << '\n';

     // nested block:
     {
           var = 1;
           auto act2 = finally([&]{ cout<< "finally!\n"; var=7; });
           cout << "var = " << var << '\n';
     } // act2 is invoked here

     cout << "var = " << var << '\n';
}// act1 is invoked here
```

Although I understand what he is trying to explain and what this code is supposed to achieve, I have problem with believing that this fragment is leek free:

```
> 1.    int* p = new int{7};                              // probably should use a unique_ptr (§5.2)
>   2.           int* buf = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));         // C-style allocation
>         
>     
> 3.         auto act1 = finally([&]{   delete p;
>                                         free(buf);             // C-style deallocation
>                                         cout<< "Goodby, Cruel world!\n";
>                                    }
>                              );
```

Why?
Because if in line two (2) we get exception thrown (assuming that there isn't call to a malloc but to a function that can actually throw, as I believe the concept that Bjarne is trying to explain is to use the finally construct and the malloc call here is irrelevant and accidental and could be replaced by any call), then if two throws then 3 will never be reached and we have resource leek from 1.
Am I correct?

Comment: If a function which acts like malloc throws an exception, but before doing so allocates some memory it doesn't then free, then it is very very naughty. Why assume such a thing? Nobody sane would write it, imo. If it threw an exception, nobody would know the address of the memory you would then have to free.

Comment: Ignoring that, though, in general terms if there is an exception throws between the allocation of memory and the creation of the "finally" object, then yes, there will be a leak.

Comment: @polkadotcadaver: The leak wouldn't be in `*buf`, but in `*p`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is happening in the above code segment is:

```
     int* p = new int{7};                              // probably should use a unique_ptr 
     int* buf = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));         // C-style allocation
```

Memory is allocated both via C++ `new` and `C` malloc. Neither of the pointer are managed, and if any code at this point were to throw then memory would be leaked. However, note that `malloc` does not throw so in isolation this code is safe.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc

```
    auto act1 = finally([&]{   delete p;
                            free(buf);             // C-style deallocation
                            cout<< "Goodby, Cruel world!\n";
                       }
                 );
```

In this code an RAII type is returned from the finally function. Which will execute the callable parameter when `act1` is destroyed (either on exception or on leaving this scope).

Because this directly follows the `malloc` we have now ensured that the memory can not leak.

The following code however would be unsafe:

```
      int* p = new int{7};                              // probably should use a unique_ptr 
     int* buf = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));         // C-style allocation

     throwing_function();

     auto act1 = finally([&]{   delete p;
                            free(buf);             // C-style deallocation
                            cout<< "Goodby, Cruel world!\n";
                       }
                 );
```

However Bjarne comment is spot on, just use a `std::unique_ptr`.

EDIT:

A use of finally:

```
database_handle dh1;
dh1.do("action...");
finally([&]{
    if(!dh1.success()) {
        dh1.rollback();
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, I was rather referring to the fact that if malloc was replaced by some other call (which could potentially throw), then leak would occur.

Comment: The last piece of code in my answers covers that. If there is a function that can throw between the point of allocation and the `finally` handler then yes code could leak. Which is why it's best just to use a smart pointer from the off.

Comment: Which basically means that the technique explained by Bjarne works only if no line of code but the first one prior to finally call throws. Bit pointless, have to say.

Comment: Bjarne is showing how you can emulate a finally clause using RAII, it's useful to know and it's be applied to a contrived example. In truth if you design your program to use RAII scrictly you shouldn't really need it but often when dealing with C APIs it might just be easier to use this in some cases. Secondly, this code works fine so long as the `finally` clause directly follows the allocation. The issue is if some can throw in between.

Comment: "The issue is if some can throw in between" - Exactly. If something can throw in between the technique is useless, and I genuinely think that it doesn't emulate finally, because it fails to clean up (if something throws in between) and I believe that's one of the main point.

Comment: Yes, but if you want it use it safely it's easy; just make sure the finally directly follows the allocation. Putting a throwing function between the allocation and finally would/should be considered a bug or mistake.

Comment: In that case you'd have to put finally after each potential allocation which is not only tedious, but we are returning to square one, where you have to keep track of allocations and deallocate them accordingly. His example is simply useless from practical point of view.

Comment: @smallB "In that case you'd have to put finally after each potential allocation which is not only tedious" Yes that is EXACTLY why you should use unqiue_ptr.It's useless for memory allocation, but there are uses for finally. See edit.

Comment: My point EXACTLY - you have to put finally after EACH possible line of code which can throw - this DO NOT emulate finally. Bjarne tries to show that his method emulates finally construct, where in reality it doesn't.

Comment: @smallB, I think it does emulate the functionality, not the elegance (if you want to call it that). That's because finally is not really idiomatic C++, using RAII strictly is. The point is that it's useful to know how you can emulate if you need to (like in the example I gave in my edit) and when you do, because it is exception (because you are using proper RAII right?) then it's more the likely only going to be used for one resource. If you are aquiring many resources and using finally to delete them you're doing it wrong.

Comment: The point is that a) Your example is wrong. Why? Because you should use RAII not the finally, using the approach you showed in your example is bad practice (I do not mean to offend you), b) Bjarne gives it as an example of emulation of finally which in fact it DOES NOT emulate it, because you HAVE TO remember to put this clause after each line of code which could potentially throw. This is no different to using new and delete. The only common thing it has with finally is its name.